# Google Line Charts will not display

Tags: html, charts, linechart

Im new to Google Charts. My html File simply has no output. Where did i do wrong?

I tried to stick to the original example (https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart), but I can't find any differences. I basically also just modified the "data code".

Thanks and greetings, anumpho

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['line']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('number'), 'Year');
data.addColumn('number'), 'Gesamt');
data.addColumn('number'), 'Allgemein bildende Pflichtschulen');
data.addColumn('number'), 'Neue Mittelschulen');
data.addColumn('number'), 'Allgemein bildende hoehere Schulen');
data.addColumn('number'), 'Sonstige allgemein bildende (Statut-)Schulen');
data.addColumn('number'), 'Berufsschulen');
data.addColumn('number'), 'Berufsbildende mittlere und hoehere Schulen');
data.addColumn('number'), 'Lehrerbildende Schulen');
data.addColumn('number'), 'Schulen und Akademien im Gesundheitswesen');


      data.addRows([
[2004,  211.612,    103.473,    0,      55.534,     0,      17.726,     31.089,     3.790,      0], 
[2005,  212.343,    102.780,    0,      56.956,     0,      18.139,     30.631,     3.837,      0], 
[2006,  226.732,    101.569,    0,      57.965,     3.850,  22.464,     31.929,     3.485,      5.470], 
[2007,  226.773,    100.181,    0,      58.572,     4.079,  23.205,     32.009,     3.448,      5.279], 
[2008,  225.749,    99.278,     0,      58.699,     4.225,  23.447,     31.562,     3.532,      5.006], 
[2009,  226.483,    97.137,     1.892,  58.050,     4.177,  23.786,     31.902,     4.774,      4.765], 
[2010,  224.697,    95.159,     3.802,  57.541,     4.521,  23.007,     32.175,     3.702,      4.790], 
[2011,  225.414,    94.761,     5.445,  57.385,     4.537,  22.160,     32.673,     4.168,      4.285], 
[2012,  225.645,    98.654,     0,      59.608,     4.435,  21.541,     33.179,     4.411,      3.817]
      ]);

      var options = {
        chart: {
          title: 'Box Office Earnings in First Two Weeks of Opening',
          subtitle: 'in millions of dollars (USD)'
        },
        width: 900,
        height: 500
      };

      var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="linechart_material"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the opening parenthesis "(" on all of your "data.addColumn" rows.

Ex:

Should be:

data.addColumn(('number'), 'Year');

Not:

data.addColumn('number'), 'Year');

Or you can just remove the closing parenthesis after 'number'on each row like this:

data.addColumn('number', 'Year');